# Store same value at rows of column B with identical negative numbers in column A of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'value1': [1, 2, 3, -4, 5, -1, 7, -2, 4], 'value2': [100, 200, 200, 300, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

value1  value2
1       100.0
2       200.0
3       200.0
-4      300.0
5       NaN
-1      NaN
7       NaN
-2      NaN
4       NaN
```

I would like to store the same value in column `value2` at those rows where the same number appears in column `value 1`, but then negative, like so:

```
value1  value2
1       100.0
2       200.0
3       200.0
-4      300.0
5       NaN
-1      100.0
7       NaN
-2      200.0
4       300.0
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `groupby()`+`abs()`+`ffill()`:

groupby the absolute values of 'value1' column then forward fill the values of 'value2' and finally assign that back to 'value2' column:

```
df['value2']=df.groupby(df['value1'].abs())['value2'].ffill()
```

output of `df`:

```
    value1  value2
0    1      100.0
1    2      200.0
2    3      200.0
3   -4      300.0
4    5      NaN
5   -1      100.0
6    7      NaN
7   -2      200.0
8    4      300.0
```